# My react app doesn't render data because of too many requets (error 429)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

I'm using RTK queries to fetch data from rapid api, sometimes the data is rendered and sometimes not. In the case when the data isn't rendered, when I inspect the console I notice that there are too many requests (status code 429) error. I actually use the RTK query only once, but because there are a bunch of things to be updated, when I submit a form for example, the re-render includes the RTK hooks to make a request and that's what probably causes the too many requests error.
My questions are:

- If there is a couple of re-renders to happen in one update, the first re-render causes the RTK hook to make a request, supposed this is immediately followed by a second re-render without a parameter change in the RTK, that means the RTK uses the data stored in cache and no request is sent to server, then why do we get 'too many requests' error.
- Is there any way to force the RTK hook to execute if only there is a dependecy change like we use in useEffect?

**UPDATE**
Here is my code:

App.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import SearchComponent from './components/SearchComponent'
import NavBarComponent from './components/NavBarComponent'
import {useGetSearchLocationQuery, useGetCurrentWeatherApiQuery} from './redux/services/weatherApi'
import {useGetCityQuery} from './redux/services/countryApi'
import {setCity} from './redux/slices/locationSlice'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import Today from './pages/Today'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Week from './pages/Week'



export const Context = createContext();

const App=()=> {

const {city} = useSelector(state => state.location )


//fetch data on first load page to get user's geolocation
const {data: fetchedCity, isLoading,  isError, isFetching} = useGetCityQuery()
//fetch city's id
const {data: locationData, isLoading: isLoadingId, isError: isErrorId} = useGetSearchLocationQuery( city || fetchedCity?.name )


if(isLoading || isLoadingId) return <p>data loading from App</p>
if(!locationData) return <p>No location data from App</p>

  return (
    <Context.Provider  value={{fetchedCity,locationData}} >
    <div className="App">
        <NavBarComponent />
       {/*contains both sideBar and the main page (today and week pages)*/}
        <div className='pageContainer'>
            <SearchComponent/>

           {/*the container of today and weekpages*/}
            <div className='mainSectionContainer'>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path= '/today/:city' element={<Today /> }/>
                    <Route path= '/week/:city' element={<Week /> }/>
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </Context.Provider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchComponent.js: This component also doesn't load data soemtimes

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import api from '../assets/api'
import '../style/searchBarStyle.css'
import {GoSearch} from 'react-icons/go'
import {TiDelete} from 'react-icons/ti'
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import {weatherIconsArray} from '../assets/api'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {setCity, setClickedCardIndex} from '../redux/slices/locationSlice'
import {useGetSearchLocationQuery, useGetCurrentWeatherApiQuery} from '../redux/services/weatherApi'
import {Context} from '../App';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const SearchComponent = () =>{

const navigate = useNavigate();
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('')
const {city} = useSelector(state =>state.location)

//locationData contains the city's id property
const {locationData, fetchedCity} = useContext(Context)

//fetch the current weather details based on the city's id
const {data: currentWeatherData, isLoading: isCurrentLoading, isError: isErrorCurrent} = useGetCurrentWeatherApiQuery(locationData?.locations[0]?.id)

//return an object of an image and a weather description to render in the DOM
const {image, description} = weatherIconsArray?.find(item => currentWeatherData?.current?.symbol === item.symbol) || {}


useEffect(()=>{

if(city === fetchedCity?.name)
setSearchInput('')

},[city])

const handleSubmit=(e) =>{
e.preventDefault();
if(!searchInput){
alert("Please set a location in the search field")
return
}

//update the city state
dispatch(setCity(searchInput))
navigate(`/today/${searchInput}`)
}


if(isCurrentLoading) return <p>is loading from searchbar</p>
if(!currentWeatherData) return <p>No current forecast available</p>

return(

    <div className='sidebarContainer'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="searchContainer">
              <GoSearch className='icon'/>
              <input
              value={searchInput}
              onChange={(e) =>{setSearchInput(e.target.value)}}
              placeholder='search'/>
              <IconContext.Provider value={{color: 'black'}}>
              <TiDelete
              onClick={()=>{setSearchInput('')}}
              className='deleteIcon'/>
              </IconContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div className='weatherImg'>
              <img src={image}/>
        </div>

        <div className='temperature'>
              <p>{currentWeatherData?.current?.temperature}°C</p>
              <p>{currentWeatherData?.time}</p>
        </div>

        <hr className='separator'/>

        <div className='weatherState'>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <p>{ `Wind speed: ${currentWeatherData?.current?.windSpeed} m/s`}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='countryAndCity'>
             <p> {`${locationData?.locations[0]?.name}, ${locationData?.locations[0]?.country}`}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    )
}
export default SearchComponent
```

Today.js: it's usually here where the problem occurs: Either data is undefined or weekData, sometimes both are undefined

```
import React , {useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import {Pagination, Navigation} from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import TwoHoursCard from '../components/TwoHoursCard'
import UvDetailsCard from '../components/UvDetailsCard'
import WindDetailsCard from '../components/WindDetailsCard'
import SunDetailsCard from '../components/SunDetailsCard'
import '../style/todayStyle.css'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {useGetNowCastQuery, useGetWeekCastQuery} from '../redux/services/weatherApi'
import {weatherIconsArray} from '../assets/api'
import {settings} from '../assets/slideSettings'
import {setCity, setClickedCardIndex, setPreviousUvIndex} from '../redux/slices/locationSlice'
import {Context} from '../App'
const Today = () =>{

const {clickedCardIndex,previousUvIndex} = useSelector(state => state.location)

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const {city} = useParams();
useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(setCity(city))
}, [city])


useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(setClickedCardIndex(-1))
dispatch(setPreviousUvIndex(NaN))
}, [clickedCardIndex])

const {locationData} = useContext(Context)

//fetch data for the upcoming 2 hours (every 15 min)
const {data, isFetching, isLoading: isLoadingNow, isError: isErrorNow} = useGetNowCastQuery(locationData?.locations[0]?.id)

//fetch data of one week, including today's highlight
const {data: weekData, isLoading: isLoadingWeek, isError: isErrorWeek} = useGetWeekCastQuery(locationData?.locations[0]?.id)

if(isLoadingNow) return <p>is loading two hours forecast</p>
if(isLoadingWeek) return <p>is loading week</p>


return(
        <>
        <p className="headers">Upcoming 2 hours:</p>
        { data ? (

        <Swiper

                modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                navigation
                pagination={{clickable: true}}
                breakpoints={{
                0: {slidesPerView: 1},
                480:{
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 16,
                },
                768:{
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 16
                },
                1024:{
                slidesPerView: 6,
                spaceBetween: 16
                },
                1150:{
                slidesPerView: 8,
                spaceBetween: 16
                }

                }}

                >
            {
              data && data?.forecast?.map((element, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide>
                <TwoHoursCard
                        key={index}
                        description={ element.symbolPhrase || weatherIconsArray.find((obj) => obj.symbol === element?.symbol)?.description}
                        image = {weatherIconsArray.find((obj) =>obj.symbol === element?.symbol).image}
                        temperature={element.temperature}
                />
                </SwiperSlide>
                ))
            }
        </Swiper>

        ) : (<p>No estimation available for the next coming 2 hours</p>)

        }

        <div>
            <p className="headers">Today&#39;s highlight:</p>

            <div className = 'todayDetails'>
                <UvDetailsCard  weekData={weekData} index={1}  clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
                <WindDetailsCard weekData={weekData} index={2} clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
                <SunDetailsCard weekData={weekData} index={3} clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
                <WindDetailsCard weekData={weekData} index={4} clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
                <WindDetailsCard weekData={weekData} index={5} clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
                <SunDetailsCard weekData={weekData} index={6} clickedCardIndex={clickedCardIndex}/>
            </div>

        </div>

        </>
)


}
export default Today
```

I also two differecent API slices because there is no realtion between them:
**coutryApi** to fetch the user's location (city) and based on the city I fetch the data I need from another API slice **weatherApi**

countryApi.js

```
    import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from 
'@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
    
    const cryptoNewsHeader = {
            'x-bingapis-sdk': 'true',
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'spott.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': '6e4bb62ec0msh084a4eb0f5c4a3bp149a1ejsn039034dc54d7',
    
    };
    
    const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoNewsHeader});
    
    export const countryApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'countryApi',
    baseQuery : fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl : 'https://spott.p.rapidapi.com/'
                }),
    endpoints: (builder) =>({
    getCity : builder.query({ query: ()=> createRequest('/places/ip/me') }),
    
    })
    })
    export const {useGetCityQuery} = countryApi
```

weatherApi

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const cryptoNewsHeader = {
    'x-bingapis-sdk': 'true',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': '6e4bb62ec0msh084a4eb0f5c4a3bp149a1ejsn039034dc54d7',
};
const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoNewsHeader});

export const weatherApi = createApi({
reducerPath: 'weatherApi',
baseQuery : fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl : 'https://foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com/',
            }),
endpoints: (builder) =>({
getSearchLocation : builder.query({ query: (city)=> createRequest(`/location/search/${city}`) }),

getCurrentWeatherApi : builder.query({ query:  (id) => createRequest(`/current/${id}`)}),

//this returns data of the forecast for every 15 min
getNowCast : builder.query({ query: (id) => createRequest(`/forecast/15minutely/${id}`)}),

getWeekCast: builder.query({ query:(id) => createRequest(`/forecast/daily/${id}&?alt=0&tempunit=C&windunit=MS&periods=8&dataset=full`)})

})
})
export const {useGetSearchLocationQuery,
                useGetCurrentWeatherApiQuery,
                useGetNowCastQuery,
                useGetWeekCastQuery} = weatherApi
```

[example when I don't get data loaded on DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDctf.png)

[Network tab in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq6FO.png)

Comment: It would help to show us the code in question, especially around where the RTK hook is and how it's used. It possibly sounds like either your cache isn't configured correct or that you are inadvertently re-instantiating it. Have you also verified for sure using network tab that re-render is causing a new network request and the 429 isn't just because of rate-limiting over a longer time period?

Comment: @adsy thanks for your answer, I updated the post and added code, I'm sorry for too much code, but the problem frequently happens with the Today class (especially if I type the url manually localhost:3000/today/a_certain_city rather than using the SearchComponent)

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the problem: The problem was sending **undefined params** to the RTK queries when I try to access a route page (*localhost:3000/today/cityName*) , and as there is no data return on an undefined param, the request is sent to the server again when there is a **re-render** and hence the too many requests error! I optimized my code using the skip parameter (conditonal fetching) and the problem was solved:

in SearchComponent.js

```js
//fetch the current weather details based on the city's id
const {
  data: currentWeatherData,
  isLoading: isCurrentLoading,
  isError: isErrorCurrent
} = useGetCurrentWeatherApiQuery(locationData?.locations?.[0]?.id, {
  skip: !city ? true : false
});
```

in Today.js

```js
//fetch data of one week, including today's highlight
const {
  data: weekData,
  isFteching: isFetchingWeek,
  isLoading: isLoadingWeek,
  isError: isErrorWeek
} = useGetWeekCastQuery(locationData?.locations?.[0]?.id, {
  skip: !city ? true : false
});
    
//fetch data for the upcoming 2 hours (every 15 min)
const {
  data,
  isFetching: isFetchingHourly,
  isLoading,
  isError: isErrorNow
} = useGetNowCastQuery(locationData?.locations?.[0]?.id, {
  skip: !city ? true : false
});
```